.net 8 Unable to use CreateMutualCertificateBindingElement
I'm trying to migrate a project using WCF from .net 4.5 to .net 8
Must of it is already migrated but I am facing a problem in implementing the CreateMutualCertificateBindingElement functionality.
From the docs it looks like it should be supported in the latest .net 8 version with the latest 8.0 package
.net 8 docs
but when I try to implement it in the code it does not find the CreateMutualCertificateBindingElement implementation.
.net 8 implementation
What am I missing here?
Any help will be greatly appreciated.
To Reproduce

Create a .net 8 console app
dotnet add package System.ServiceModel.Primitives --version 8.0.0
try to create the security binging element -
SecurityBindingElement security = SecurityBindingElement.CreateMutualCertificateBindingElement();


I found that this method does not exist in this class in the Object browser.
System.ServiceModel.Primitives v8.0.0-System.ServiceModel.Channels-SecurityBindingElement

Feedback may be required on the content of the documentation.
In fact, many Servicemodel methods do not run on .net core. You may need to readjust your code.
